# How to display mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss am/pm in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have small doubt in MySQL how to display  `mm/dd/yyyy` using `dateformat` in MySQL
and any null or empty in that field  just I want display as it is.

```
date
null
null
1/3/2013 9:29:33 AM
1/3/2013 10:42:53 AM
1/2/2013 10:54:00 AM
1/2/2013 2:41:19 PM
1/2/2013 2:41:25 PM
null
```

I tried query  using `dateformat`

```
select DATE_FORMAT(checkin,'%c/%e/%Y %h:%i:%s %p')as date  from emp
```

that time it displays like below

```
0/0/0000 12:00:00 AM
0/0/0000 12:00:00 AM
1/3/2013 09:29:33 AM
1/3/2013 10:42:53 AM
1/2/2013 10:54:00 AM
1/2/2013 02:41:19 PM
1/2/2013 02:41:25 PM
0/0/0000 12:00:00 AM
```

Here we have 3 records have null values that time I want display as it is but here
it came `0/0/0000 12:00:00 AM`. I don't need this one while null or empty records. Please tell me how solve this issue in MySQL query level?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you wish to have the null values, remain null, and only format the dates, so try using either of the following:

```
SELECT IF(checkin IS NOT NULL, DATE_FORMAT(checkin,'%c/%e/%Y %h:%i:%s %p'), NULL ) AS date
FROM   emp
```

OR

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN checkin IS NOT NULL THEN DATE_FORMAT(checkin,'%c/%e/%Y %h:%i:%s %p')
        ELSE NULL
    END AS date
FROM  emp
```

Comment: HI Tried given above query still its came 0/0/0000 12:00:00 AM when null or empty records on that fields.any other way please tell me that query.

Comment: @user1623352, could you please clarify what you mean by _empty_ record? Do you mean that the values are either null or it is set to a default datetime value? What is this _empty_ value you are referring to? I can modify my query to accommodate that, but I need to know all the possible conditions you are talking about here. Your sample data in your post didn't show _empty_ data, it only showed nulls.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select if(checkin is null , null ,DATE_FORMAT(checkin,'%c/%e/%Y %h:%i:%s %p') )as date
from emp
```